# Given $F$ is a finite field with characteristic $p$, let $p(x) \in F[x]$ be inseparable and irreducible, then $p(x) = q(x^p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Given $F$ is a finite field with characteristic $p$, let $p(x) \in F[x]$ be inseparable and irreducible, then $p(x) = q(x^p)$.

Here is an attempt by me,
suppose $p(x) \in F[x]$ is inseparable, then $p(x)$ has a multiple zero $\alpha$. We know that $p(x)$ has a multiple zero if and only if $p(\alpha) = p'(\alpha) = 0$, thus the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ divides both $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$. Since $p(x)$ is irreducible, it has same degree with the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Therefore, we must have $p'(x) = 0$, this shows that $p(x) = q(x^p)$ for some $q(x) \in F[x]$.

Comment: There are no irreducible inseparables over finite fields,

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I think I misunderstood the question, let me make some edit.

Comment: Are you asking for people to verify your solution? Then please add the appropriate tag: `[solution-verification]` or `[proof-verification]`. If not, then please clarify what you know and what you are asking.

Comment: May be helpful: a polynomial is separable iff it is relatively prime to its derivative.

Comment: If $F$ is a finite field, $p(x)\in F[x]$ is irreducible, and $p(x)=q(x^p)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$, then $2+2=5$. Because over a finite field, all irreducible polynomials are separable: finite fields are perfect. Your premise is impossible to meet. Note that over a finite field of characteristic $p$, every element is a $p$th power, so if $p(x) = a_nx^{pn}+\cdots + a_1x^p + a_0$, then $p(x) = (b_nx^n+\cdots+b_1x+b_0)^p$, where $b_i^p=a_i$, and hence $p(x)$ is not irreducible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I just realized that. I just removed that assumption.

Comment: I still see it in the title and in the post. If you remove the assumption that $F$ is finite and replace it with “$F$ is of characteristic $p\gt 0$”, then you’ve got a true statement. “Finite” is not equivalent to “positive characteristic”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry that I made my question confusing. What I really want to ask is, suppose $F$ is a finite filed with characteristic $p$, and $p(x)$ is inseparable and irreducible (I'm trying to make a contradiction argument here), can I find a $q(x) \in F[x]$ such that $p(x) = q(x^p)$?

Comment: @Andy: Again: if $F$ is a finite field then there are **no** polynomials over $F$ that are both inseparable and irreducible, so the entire premise of your question is impossible to achieve. Since the premise is false, **any** conclusion follows, including that $2+2=5$.

Comment: @Andy: And, again, in any field of characteristic $p$, if $p(x)$ is irreducible and has multiple roots, then you must have that $p’(x)=0$, and therefore that if $p(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, then $ka_k=0$ for all $k$. From that you deduce that $a_k=0$ for $\gcd(k,p)=0$, so only the powers of $p$ of $x$ show up.

Comment: @I want to prove that in a finite field $F$ with characteristic of $p$, irreducible implies separable by a contradiction. So suppose that $p(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible and inseparable, also suppose $p(x) = q(x^p)$ for some $q(x) \in F[x]$, then I can find a contradiction. But I don't have the part where $p(x) = q(x^p)$ for some $q(x) \in F[x]$, this is what I am asking.

Comment: To use the same letter for a polynomial and for the characteristic of the field doesn't really  make things clearer...

Comment: The argument is essentially correct, though gappy. You should note that the root need not lie in $F$, but in an extension; and perhaps explain how you go from $p’(x)=0$ to $p(x)=q(x^p)$ for some $q$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much for your comments! I was pretty confused with all this finite fields and finite characteristic stuff before. Now I feel more comfortable about this material.